# How to pass user id to view with firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I am working on a social media app and I am having trouble displaying a Profile of a specific user. I am able to do it with currentUser?.uid but I don't know how to pass a different id/user to a profile view. Sorry if this explanation is confusing, I'm also having a hard time putting it into words.

This is my view that fetches the currently logged in user and displays their username:

```
import SwiftUI

class TestProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var qUser: User?
    
    init() {
        fetchCurrentUser()
    }
    
    func fetchCurrentUser() {
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, err in
            if let err = err {
                print("\(err)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = snapshot?.data() else { return }
            print(data)
            
            self.qUser = .init(data: data)
        }
    }
}

struct TestProfileView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = TestProfileViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(vm.qUser?.username ?? "No User")
    }
}

struct TestProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestProfileView()
    }
}
```

This is the view, where I want to use the ID to fetch a user from my database and use it for a Profile View, ike how I did with the currentUser:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestSongVIew: View {
    let testUsername = "John"
    let testUserID = "123123"
    
    @State var showingUserProfile = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Open \(testUsername)'s Profile") {
                
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingUserProfile, onDismiss: nil) {
            TestProfileView()
        }
    }
}

struct TestSongVIew_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestSongVIew()
    }
}
```

**Here is my FirebaseManager code**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class FirebaseManager: NSObject {
    let auth: Auth
    let storage: Storage
    let firestore: Firestore
    
    static let shared = FirebaseManager()
    
    override init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        self.auth = Auth.auth()
        self.storage = Storage.storage()
        self.firestore = Firestore.firestore()
        
        super .init()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @phast, first of all let me understand what exactly you are doing. I can see that you are fetching the data for the current user, but of course you have to fetch foreigners user data as well. Not via the auth method.

Comment: I just saw, it is exactly, how you do it in the fetchCurrentUser() function, but not with the current (and saved) uid, instead you have to use the uid of the specific user. I don't see such a function. Do you do that somewhere and if so, do you see in the debugger that you are getting the right data?

Comment: That is my issue. I'm not sure how to pass the userID to the fetchForeignUser() function when I click the button in TestSongView.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this, and they all depend on how you set up the navigation for your app.

I'm currently working on a blog post / video to demonstrate how to monitor authentication state in a SwiftUI app. To demonstrate how to implement your use case, I added a profile screen that you can use in two ways:

1. You can navigate to the profile screen from the app's settings screen. This will show the user profile of the currently signed in user.
2. You can navigate to the profile screen from a `List` view showing all user profiles in your user profile collection in Firestore. This might be useful if you want to implement a high score screen that allows the user to navigate to the profile screen for each of the top 10 players in a game.

Ok, here goes:

### Profile

#### The profile model

```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Profile: Identifiable, Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String? = ""
  var nickname: String
}

extension Profile {
  static let empty = Profile(nickname: "")
}
```

#### The profile view model

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
  // MARK: - Output
  @Published var profile: Profile
  
  init(profile: Profile) {
    self.profile = profile
  }
  
  init(uid: String) {
    self.profile = Profile.empty
    fetchProfile(uid)
  }
  
  // MARK: - Private attributes
  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
  
  func fetchProfile(_ uid: String) {
    db.collection("profiles")
      .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
      .getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
          print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
        }
        else {
          if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
            if let document = querySnapshot.documents.first {
              do {
                self.profile = try document.data(as: Profile.self)
              }
              catch {
                
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

#### The profile view

```swift
struct ProfileView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ProfileViewModel
  
  init(profile: Profile) {
    self.viewModel = ProfileViewModel(profile: profile)
  }
  
  init(uid: String) {
    self.viewModel = ProfileViewModel(uid: uid)
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      Text(viewModel.profile.nickname)
    }
    .navigationTitle("Details")
  }
}

struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ProfileView(profile: Profile(nickname: "freter"))
  }
}
```

### Settings

#### The settings view model

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine
import FirebaseAuth

class SettingsViewModel: ObservableObject {

  // MARK: - Output
  @Published var email: String = ""
  @Published var idToken: String = ""
  @Published var user: User?
  
  @Published var authenticationState: AuthenticationState = .unauthenticated
  
  // MARK: - Dependencies
  private var authenticationService: AuthenticationService?
  
  func connect(authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    if self.authenticationService == nil {
      self.authenticationService = authenticationService
      
      self.authenticationService?
        .$authenticationState
        .assign(to: &$authenticationState)
      
      self.authenticationService?
        .$user
        .assign(to: &$user)
      
      $user
        .map { $0?.email }
        .replaceNil(with: "(no email address)")
        .assign(to: &$email)
    }
  }
  
  @MainActor
  func refreshIDToken() {
    Task {
      do {
          idToken = try await user?.idTokenForcingRefresh(true) ?? ""
      }
      catch {
        idToken = error.localizedDescription
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

#### The settings view

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel = SettingsViewModel()
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  @EnvironmentObject var authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  
  @State private var presentingLoginScreen = false
  
  var loginButton: some View {
    Button(authenticationService.authenticationState == .unauthenticated ? "Login" : "Logout") {
      if authenticationService.authenticationState == .unauthenticated {
        presentingLoginScreen.toggle()
      }
      else {
        authenticationService.signOut()
      }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      Section {
        Label("Help & Feedback", systemImage: "questionmark.circle")
        Label("About", systemImage: "info.circle")
      }
      Section {
        Label(viewModel.email, systemImage: "at")
        Label(viewModel.idToken, systemImage: "person")
        Button(action: viewModel.refreshIDToken) {
          Text("Refresh ID token")
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView(uid: viewModel.user?.uid ?? "unknown")) {
          Label("Show user profile", systemImage: "person")
        }
      } header: {
        Text("User Details")
      }

      Section {
        loginButton
      }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $presentingLoginScreen) {
      LoginView()
    }
    .navigationTitle("Settings")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
        Button("Done") {
          dismiss()
        }
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
      viewModel.connect(authenticationService: authenticationService)
    }
  }
}

struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    NavigationView {
      SettingsView()
        .environmentObject(AuthenticationService())
    }
  }
}
```

### Authentication

#### The authentication service

```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

enum AuthenticationState {
  case unauthenticated
  case authenticating
  case authenticated
}

class AuthenticationService: ObservableObject {
  // MARK: - Output
  @Published var authenticationState: AuthenticationState = .unauthenticated
  @Published var errorMessage: String = ""
  @Published var user: User?
  
  init() {
    registerAuthStateListener()
  }
  
  @MainActor
  func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String) async -> Bool {
    authenticationState = .authenticating
    do {
      try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
      return true
    }
    catch {
      await MainActor.run {
        errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
        authenticationState = .unauthenticated
      }
      print(error)
      return false
    }
  }
  
  func signOut() {
    do  {
      try Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
    catch {
      print(error)
    }
  }
  
  private var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
  private func registerAuthStateListener() {
    if handle == nil {
      handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        Task {
          await MainActor.run {
            self.user = user
            
            if let user = user {
              self.authenticationState = .authenticated
              print("User \(user.uid) signed in. Email: \(user.email ?? "(no email address set)"), anonymous: \(user.isAnonymous)")
            }
            else {
              self.authenticationState = .unauthenticated
              print("User signed out.")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

#### The login view model

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
  // MARK: - Input
  @Published var email: String = ""
  @Published var password: String = ""

  // MARK: - Output
  @Published var isValid: Bool  = false
  @Published var authenticationState: AuthenticationState = .unauthenticated
  @Published var errorMessage: String = ""
  @Published var user: User?
  
  // MARK: - Dependencies
  private var authenticationService: AuthenticationService?
  
  func connect(authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    if self.authenticationService == nil {
      self.authenticationService = authenticationService
      
      self.authenticationService?
        .$authenticationState
        .assign(to: &$authenticationState)
      
      self.authenticationService?
        .$errorMessage
        .assign(to: &$errorMessage)
      
      self.authenticationService?
        .$user
        .assign(to: &$user)
      
      Publishers.CombineLatest($email, $password)
        .map { !($0.isEmpty && $1.isEmpty) }
        .print()
        .assign(to: &$isValid)
    }
  }
  
  func signInWithEmailPassword() async -> Bool {
    if let authenticationService = authenticationService {
      return await authenticationService.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
    }
    else {
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

#### The login view

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum FocusableField: Hashable {
  case email
  case password
}

struct LoginView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel = LoginViewModel()
  @EnvironmentObject var authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  
  @FocusState private var focus: FocusableField?
  
  private func signInWithEmailPassword() {
    Task {
      if await viewModel.signInWithEmailPassword() == true {
        dismiss()
      }
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Image("Login")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(minHeight: 0)
      Text("Login")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
      
      HStack {
        Image(systemName: "at")
        TextField("Email", text: $viewModel.email)
          .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
          .disableAutocorrection(true)
          .focused($focus, equals: .email)
          .submitLabel(.next)
          .onSubmit {
            self.focus = .password
          }
      }
      .padding(.vertical, 6)
      .background(Divider(), alignment: .bottom)
      .padding(.bottom, 4)
      
      HStack {
        Image(systemName: "lock")
        SecureField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
          .focused($focus, equals: .password)
          .submitLabel(.go)
          .onSubmit {
            signInWithEmailPassword()
          }
      }
      .padding(.vertical, 6)
      .background(Divider(), alignment: .bottom)
      .padding(.bottom, 8)
      
      if !viewModel.errorMessage.isEmpty {
        VStack {
          Text(viewModel.errorMessage)
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemRed))
        }
      }
      
      Button(action: signInWithEmailPassword) {
        if viewModel.authenticationState != .authenticating {
          Text("Login")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        else {
          ProgressView()
            .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .white))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
      }
      .disabled(!viewModel.isValid)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
      .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
      .controlSize(.large)
      
      HStack {
        VStack { Divider() }
        Text("or")
        VStack { Divider() }
      }
      
      Button(action: { }) {
        Image(systemName: "applelogo")
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
      }
      .foregroundColor(.black)
      .buttonStyle(.bordered)
      .controlSize(.large)
      
      HStack {
        Text("Don't have an account yet?")
        Button(action: {}) {
          Text("Sign up")
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
      }
      .padding([.top, .bottom], 50)
    }
    .onAppear {
      viewModel.connect(authenticationService: authenticationService)
    }
    .listStyle(.plain)
    .padding()
  }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    Group {
      LoginView()
        .environmentObject(AuthenticationService())
      LoginView()
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        .environmentObject(AuthenticationService())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will be trying to decipher all the code tonight and tomorrow. Option 2 is what I'm trying to achieve. How would I pass a uid to the Profile View Model and Profile that you've provided? I'm very new to Firebase and its code structure.