# Swift UI combine not publishing changes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, combine

I am following this tutorial (https://peterfriese.dev/posts/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part2/#making-the-task-repository-user-aware) to create a similar app connected to firebase firestore and firebase auth.

I want to enable the user to change their display name via Firebase SDK. The problem is, that the updated user object does not get published - hence the new display name only shows after restarting the app. Here's the relevant code:

**AuthenticationService.swift**

```
class AuthenticationService: ObservableObject {

@Published var user: User?
...

func updateDisplayName(displayName: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {
      if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let changeRequest = user.createProfileChangeRequest()
        changeRequest.displayName = displayName
        changeRequest.commitChanges { error in
          if let error = error {
            completionHandler(.failure(error))
          }
          else {
            if let updatedUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
              print("Successfully updated display name for user [\(user.uid)] to [\(updatedUser.displayName ?? "(empty)")]")
              // force update the local user to trigger the publisher -> NOT WORKING 
              self.user = updatedUser
              completionHandler(.success(updatedUser))
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

** ViewModel.swift **

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Injected var authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    
    var userId: String = "unknown"
    var username: String = "unknown"
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        
        authenticationService.$user
            .compactMap { user in
                user?.displayName
            }
            .assign(to: \.username, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        authenticationService.$user
            .compactMap { user in
                user?.email
            }
            .assign(to: \.userId, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        
        // (re)load data if user changes
        authenticationService.$user
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { user in
                self.fetchPrivateNotes()
                self.fetchSharedNotes()
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

I expect the attribute username in ViewModel.swift to be updated with the new display name, so any views that bind to that published attribute show it immediately.

Comment: Your userId and username in your VeiwModel class are not @Published. Shouldn't that be the case if you want to distribute it to via this ViewModel ObservableObject?

Comment: Good point! I changed it, however the username attribute still does not update. It seems as if the combine publisher (authenticationService.$user...) is not working. Did I make a mistake with that?

Comment: what's `@Injected` doing? Is it perhaps changing the value of authenticationService on you after init(), or something like that? That would definitely cause this issue. Try stepping through init() in the debugger and take a look at authenticationService. And, try dropping the injection and making `var authenticationService = AuthenticationService()`... does that give you different behavior?

Comment: @d-reic, even if it takes some time to update the code, @peter-friese wrote another tutorial this year in a different post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71471294/how-to-pass-user-id-to-view-with-firebase. I guess it is more what you need. Btw. as you can see there, even userId and email became `@Published`.